# Why does this lazrs wheel fail installing on Python3.6 Linux

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel, las

I'm trying to install the lazrs wheel in a Docker image. It uses a variant of Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 3.6. There is a wheel for this [version](https://pypi.org/project/lazrs/0.4.0/#files), but it fails installing with the message:

```sh
$ /usr/bin/python3.6 -m pip install lazrs-0.4.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl 
ERROR: lazrs-0.4.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Yet I am using Python 3.6, Linux and an x86_64 system. So what about the platform is unsupported / wrong?

```sh
$ /usr/bin/python3.6 --version
Python 3.6.2

$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS"

$ uname -a
Linux 4cd992b95aee 4.15.0-1098-gcp #111~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 13 19:05:08 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What is special about this Linux environment is that it builds on the nvidia docker image [nvidia/cuda:9.0-base-ubuntu16.04](https://hub.docker.com/layers/cuda/nvidia/cuda/9.0-base-ubuntu16.04/images/sha256-1780ec4996b4f4338dfa94bcf236c37be258c9a99722cba99df565a7fa306247?context=explore), but I don't see why that would matter. Installing lazrs in a Python 3.6 docker image does work, but unfortunately I need this nVidia image.

Does anyone understand what is going wrong?

**Edit 1** Command outputs:

```sh
$ /usr/bin/python3.6 -m pip debug --verbose
WARNING: This command is only meant for debugging. Do not use this with automation for parsing and getting these details, since the output and options of this command may change without notice.
pip version: pip 21.3.1 from /home/a.nieuwland/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
sys.version: 3.6.10 (default, Dec 19 2019, 23:04:32) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
sys.executable: /usr/bin/python3.6
sys.getdefaultencoding: utf-8
sys.getfilesystemencoding: utf-8
locale.getpreferredencoding: UTF-8
sys.platform: linux
sys.implementation:
  name: cpython
'cert' config value: Not specified
REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE: None
CURL_CA_BUNDLE: None
pip._vendor.certifi.where(): /home/a.nieuwland/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/certifi/cacert.pem
pip._vendor.DEBUNDLED: False
vendored library versions:
  CacheControl==0.12.6
  colorama==0.4.4
  distlib==0.3.3
  distro==1.6.0
  html5lib==1.1
  msgpack==1.0.2 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
  packaging==21.0
  pep517==0.12.0
  platformdirs==2.4.0
  progress==1.6
  pyparsing==2.4.7
  requests==2.26.0
  certifi==2021.05.30
  chardet==4.0.0
  idna==3.2
  urllib3==1.26.7
  resolvelib==0.8.0
  setuptools==44.0.0 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
  six==1.16.0
  tenacity==8.0.1 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
  tomli==1.0.3
  webencodings==0.5.1 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
Compatible tags: 354
  cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_23_x86_64
  cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_22_x86_64
  cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_21_x86_64
  cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_20_x86_64
  cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_19_x86_64
  cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_18_x86_64
  cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64
  cp36-cp36m-manylinux2014_x86_64
  cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_16_x86_64
  cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_15_x86_64
  cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_14_x86_64
  cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_13_x86_64
  cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_12_x86_64
  cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64
  cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_11_x86_64
  cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_10_x86_64
  cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_9_x86_64
  cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_8_x86_64
  cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_7_x86_64
  cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_6_x86_64
  cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_5_x86_64
  cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64
  cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_23_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_22_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_21_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_20_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_19_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_18_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_16_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_15_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_14_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_13_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_12_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_11_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_10_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_9_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_8_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_7_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_6_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_5_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-linux_x86_64
  cp36-none-manylinux_2_23_x86_64
  cp36-none-manylinux_2_22_x86_64
  cp36-none-manylinux_2_21_x86_64
  cp36-none-manylinux_2_20_x86_64
  cp36-none-manylinux_2_19_x86_64
  cp36-none-manylinux_2_18_x86_64
  cp36-none-manylinux_2_17_x86_64
  cp36-none-manylinux2014_x86_64
  cp36-none-manylinux_2_16_x86_64
  cp36-none-manylinux_2_15_x86_64
  cp36-none-manylinux_2_14_x86_64
  cp36-none-manylinux_2_13_x86_64
  cp36-none-manylinux_2_12_x86_64
  cp36-none-manylinux2010_x86_64
  cp36-none-manylinux_2_11_x86_64
  cp36-none-manylinux_2_10_x86_64
  cp36-none-manylinux_2_9_x86_64
  cp36-none-manylinux_2_8_x86_64
  cp36-none-manylinux_2_7_x86_64
  cp36-none-manylinux_2_6_x86_64
  cp36-none-manylinux_2_5_x86_64
  cp36-none-manylinux1_x86_64
  cp36-none-linux_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-manylinux_2_23_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-manylinux_2_22_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-manylinux_2_21_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-manylinux_2_20_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-manylinux_2_19_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-manylinux_2_18_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-manylinux_2_16_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-manylinux_2_15_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-manylinux_2_14_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-manylinux_2_13_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-manylinux_2_12_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-manylinux_2_11_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-manylinux_2_10_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-manylinux_2_9_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-manylinux_2_8_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-manylinux_2_7_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-manylinux_2_6_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-manylinux_2_5_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-linux_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-manylinux_2_23_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-manylinux_2_22_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-manylinux_2_21_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-manylinux_2_20_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-manylinux_2_19_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-manylinux_2_18_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-manylinux_2_16_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-manylinux_2_15_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-manylinux_2_14_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-manylinux_2_13_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-manylinux_2_12_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-manylinux_2_11_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-manylinux_2_10_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-manylinux_2_9_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-manylinux_2_8_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-manylinux_2_7_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-manylinux_2_6_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-manylinux_2_5_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-linux_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-manylinux_2_23_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-manylinux_2_22_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-manylinux_2_21_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-manylinux_2_20_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-manylinux_2_19_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-manylinux_2_18_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-manylinux_2_16_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-manylinux_2_15_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-manylinux_2_14_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-manylinux_2_13_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-manylinux_2_12_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-manylinux_2_11_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-manylinux_2_10_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-manylinux_2_9_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-manylinux_2_8_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-manylinux_2_7_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-manylinux_2_6_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-manylinux_2_5_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-linux_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-manylinux_2_23_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-manylinux_2_22_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-manylinux_2_21_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-manylinux_2_20_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-manylinux_2_19_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-manylinux_2_18_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-manylinux_2_16_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-manylinux_2_15_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-manylinux_2_14_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-manylinux_2_13_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-manylinux_2_12_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-manylinux_2_11_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-manylinux_2_10_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-manylinux_2_9_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-manylinux_2_8_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-manylinux_2_7_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-manylinux_2_6_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-manylinux_2_5_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-linux_x86_64
  py36-none-manylinux_2_23_x86_64
  py36-none-manylinux_2_22_x86_64
  py36-none-manylinux_2_21_x86_64
  py36-none-manylinux_2_20_x86_64
  py36-none-manylinux_2_19_x86_64
  py36-none-manylinux_2_18_x86_64
  py36-none-manylinux_2_17_x86_64
  py36-none-manylinux2014_x86_64
  py36-none-manylinux_2_16_x86_64
  py36-none-manylinux_2_15_x86_64
  py36-none-manylinux_2_14_x86_64
  py36-none-manylinux_2_13_x86_64
  py36-none-manylinux_2_12_x86_64
  py36-none-manylinux2010_x86_64
  py36-none-manylinux_2_11_x86_64
  py36-none-manylinux_2_10_x86_64
  py36-none-manylinux_2_9_x86_64
  py36-none-manylinux_2_8_x86_64
  py36-none-manylinux_2_7_x86_64
  py36-none-manylinux_2_6_x86_64
  py36-none-manylinux_2_5_x86_64
  py36-none-manylinux1_x86_64
  py36-none-linux_x86_64
  py3-none-manylinux_2_23_x86_64
  py3-none-manylinux_2_22_x86_64
  py3-none-manylinux_2_21_x86_64
  py3-none-manylinux_2_20_x86_64
  py3-none-manylinux_2_19_x86_64
  py3-none-manylinux_2_18_x86_64
  py3-none-manylinux_2_17_x86_64
  py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64
  py3-none-manylinux_2_16_x86_64
  py3-none-manylinux_2_15_x86_64
  py3-none-manylinux_2_14_x86_64
  py3-none-manylinux_2_13_x86_64
  py3-none-manylinux_2_12_x86_64
  py3-none-manylinux2010_x86_64
  py3-none-manylinux_2_11_x86_64
  py3-none-manylinux_2_10_x86_64
  py3-none-manylinux_2_9_x86_64
  py3-none-manylinux_2_8_x86_64
  py3-none-manylinux_2_7_x86_64
  py3-none-manylinux_2_6_x86_64
  py3-none-manylinux_2_5_x86_64
  py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64
  py3-none-linux_x86_64
  py35-none-manylinux_2_23_x86_64
  py35-none-manylinux_2_22_x86_64
  py35-none-manylinux_2_21_x86_64
  py35-none-manylinux_2_20_x86_64
  py35-none-manylinux_2_19_x86_64
  py35-none-manylinux_2_18_x86_64
  py35-none-manylinux_2_17_x86_64
  py35-none-manylinux2014_x86_64
  py35-none-manylinux_2_16_x86_64
  py35-none-manylinux_2_15_x86_64
  py35-none-manylinux_2_14_x86_64
  py35-none-manylinux_2_13_x86_64
  py35-none-manylinux_2_12_x86_64
  py35-none-manylinux2010_x86_64
  py35-none-manylinux_2_11_x86_64
  py35-none-manylinux_2_10_x86_64
  py35-none-manylinux_2_9_x86_64
  py35-none-manylinux_2_8_x86_64
  py35-none-manylinux_2_7_x86_64
  py35-none-manylinux_2_6_x86_64
  py35-none-manylinux_2_5_x86_64
  py35-none-manylinux1_x86_64
  py35-none-linux_x86_64
  py34-none-manylinux_2_23_x86_64
  py34-none-manylinux_2_22_x86_64
  py34-none-manylinux_2_21_x86_64
  py34-none-manylinux_2_20_x86_64
  py34-none-manylinux_2_19_x86_64
  py34-none-manylinux_2_18_x86_64
  py34-none-manylinux_2_17_x86_64
  py34-none-manylinux2014_x86_64
  py34-none-manylinux_2_16_x86_64
  py34-none-manylinux_2_15_x86_64
  py34-none-manylinux_2_14_x86_64
  py34-none-manylinux_2_13_x86_64
  py34-none-manylinux_2_12_x86_64
  py34-none-manylinux2010_x86_64
  py34-none-manylinux_2_11_x86_64
  py34-none-manylinux_2_10_x86_64
  py34-none-manylinux_2_9_x86_64
  py34-none-manylinux_2_8_x86_64
  py34-none-manylinux_2_7_x86_64
  py34-none-manylinux_2_6_x86_64
  py34-none-manylinux_2_5_x86_64
  py34-none-manylinux1_x86_64
  py34-none-linux_x86_64
  py33-none-manylinux_2_23_x86_64
  py33-none-manylinux_2_22_x86_64
  py33-none-manylinux_2_21_x86_64
  py33-none-manylinux_2_20_x86_64
  py33-none-manylinux_2_19_x86_64
  py33-none-manylinux_2_18_x86_64
  py33-none-manylinux_2_17_x86_64
  py33-none-manylinux2014_x86_64
  py33-none-manylinux_2_16_x86_64
  py33-none-manylinux_2_15_x86_64
  py33-none-manylinux_2_14_x86_64
  py33-none-manylinux_2_13_x86_64
  py33-none-manylinux_2_12_x86_64
  py33-none-manylinux2010_x86_64
  py33-none-manylinux_2_11_x86_64
  py33-none-manylinux_2_10_x86_64
  py33-none-manylinux_2_9_x86_64
  py33-none-manylinux_2_8_x86_64
  py33-none-manylinux_2_7_x86_64
  py33-none-manylinux_2_6_x86_64
  py33-none-manylinux_2_5_x86_64
  py33-none-manylinux1_x86_64
  py33-none-linux_x86_64
  py32-none-manylinux_2_23_x86_64
  py32-none-manylinux_2_22_x86_64
  py32-none-manylinux_2_21_x86_64
  py32-none-manylinux_2_20_x86_64
  py32-none-manylinux_2_19_x86_64
  py32-none-manylinux_2_18_x86_64
  py32-none-manylinux_2_17_x86_64
  py32-none-manylinux2014_x86_64
  py32-none-manylinux_2_16_x86_64
  py32-none-manylinux_2_15_x86_64
  py32-none-manylinux_2_14_x86_64
  py32-none-manylinux_2_13_x86_64
  py32-none-manylinux_2_12_x86_64
  py32-none-manylinux2010_x86_64
  py32-none-manylinux_2_11_x86_64
  py32-none-manylinux_2_10_x86_64
  py32-none-manylinux_2_9_x86_64
  py32-none-manylinux_2_8_x86_64
  py32-none-manylinux_2_7_x86_64
  py32-none-manylinux_2_6_x86_64
  py32-none-manylinux_2_5_x86_64
  py32-none-manylinux1_x86_64
  py32-none-linux_x86_64
  py31-none-manylinux_2_23_x86_64
  py31-none-manylinux_2_22_x86_64
  py31-none-manylinux_2_21_x86_64
  py31-none-manylinux_2_20_x86_64
  py31-none-manylinux_2_19_x86_64
  py31-none-manylinux_2_18_x86_64
  py31-none-manylinux_2_17_x86_64
  py31-none-manylinux2014_x86_64
  py31-none-manylinux_2_16_x86_64
  py31-none-manylinux_2_15_x86_64
  py31-none-manylinux_2_14_x86_64
  py31-none-manylinux_2_13_x86_64
  py31-none-manylinux_2_12_x86_64
  py31-none-manylinux2010_x86_64
  py31-none-manylinux_2_11_x86_64
  py31-none-manylinux_2_10_x86_64
  py31-none-manylinux_2_9_x86_64
  py31-none-manylinux_2_8_x86_64
  py31-none-manylinux_2_7_x86_64
  py31-none-manylinux_2_6_x86_64
  py31-none-manylinux_2_5_x86_64
  py31-none-manylinux1_x86_64
  py31-none-linux_x86_64
  py30-none-manylinux_2_23_x86_64
  py30-none-manylinux_2_22_x86_64
  py30-none-manylinux_2_21_x86_64
  py30-none-manylinux_2_20_x86_64
  py30-none-manylinux_2_19_x86_64
  py30-none-manylinux_2_18_x86_64
  py30-none-manylinux_2_17_x86_64
  py30-none-manylinux2014_x86_64
  py30-none-manylinux_2_16_x86_64
  py30-none-manylinux_2_15_x86_64
  py30-none-manylinux_2_14_x86_64
  py30-none-manylinux_2_13_x86_64
  py30-none-manylinux_2_12_x86_64
  py30-none-manylinux2010_x86_64
  py30-none-manylinux_2_11_x86_64
  py30-none-manylinux_2_10_x86_64
  py30-none-manylinux_2_9_x86_64
  py30-none-manylinux_2_8_x86_64
  py30-none-manylinux_2_7_x86_64
  py30-none-manylinux_2_6_x86_64
  py30-none-manylinux_2_5_x86_64
  py30-none-manylinux1_x86_64
  py30-none-linux_x86_64
  cp36-none-any
  py36-none-any
  py3-none-any
  py35-none-any
  py34-none-any
  py33-none-any
  py32-none-any
  py31-none-any
  py30-none-any
```

```sh
$ python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"
64
```

Comment: To debug: show us the long text output of `/usr/bin/python3.6 -m pip debug --verbose` . Just in case let's test Python 32/64-bitness: `python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"`

Comment: Thanks, I updated the original post with the outputs.

Comment: I think I see it. The latest number outputted is `cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_23_x86_64` while the wheel has `2_24`. What is this the version of?

Comment: Seems it's the minimal version of `glibc`: https://peps.python.org/pep-0600/ . Perhaps the wheels were built on Ubuntu 18 or higher. I suspect you need to compile them from the source code.